# Typing issue when using effects in ngrx

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm facing an issue of typing when I call a web service on an effect

I have created the effect here

```
$LoadSchedulingsByMission = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<any>(ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirection),
    mergeMap(action =>
      this.apiCallsService.getDirections(action.payload, '2016-04-18').pipe(
        map(trips => ({ type: ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirectionSuccess, payload: trips })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

the `GetSchedulesByDirection` Action

```
export class GetDirections implements Action {
  public readonly type = ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirection;
  constructor(public payload: string[]) {}
}
```

Then I call a http service

```
getDirections(data: string[], date:string) {
  const groupByDirection:any={};
  data.map(elm=> {
    let dirUrl=`.....date=${date}&directions=${elm}`
    this.http.get<ISchedules>(dirUrl).pipe(map(dirData=>{
      groupByDirection[elm].push(dirData.data)
    }))
  })
  return groupByDirection as ISchedules;
}
```

Finally `Success` Action

```
export class GetDirectionsSuccess implements Action {
  public readonly type = ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirectionSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: ISchedules) {}
}
```

The reducers

```
case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirection: {
  return {
    ...state,
  };
}
case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDirectionSuccess: {
  return {
    ...state,
    directions: action.payload
  };
}
```

I'm getting this error

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable | ((...args: any[]) => Observable)'.
>   Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.
>       Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.

**Update**

I'm noticing that `getDirection` service function is returning an object, but in other same behaviour effects , services are returning Observable of objects.

So i modified my service to and error disappeared.

```
getDirections(data: string[], date:string) {
  const groupByDirection:any={};
  data.map(elm=> {
    let dirUrl=`...date=${date}&directions=${elm}`
    this.http.get<ISchedules>(dirUrl).pipe(map(dirData=>{
      groupByDirection[elm].push(dirData.data)
    }))
  })
  return of(groupByDirection);
```

Is it a a right solution ?

Comment: what about catchError(() => NEVER) ?

Comment: Even by deleting it I get the same error

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247613/ngrx-8-effects-type-observableunknown-is-not-assignable-to-type-observabl/57612215#57612215). If you first remove the createEffect wrapper you’ll be able to find out what’s wrong.

Comment: That does not help me

Comment: You don’t get a different (more helpful) error message by removing the createEffect wrapper?

Comment: No as I have updated my message , I should return an observable inside the service , VScode is detecting it only when createeffect is not commented